# rndc delzone {zonename} : permission denied

Tags: permissions, bind, rndc

System is:

`Debian GNU/Linux 8.2 (jessie)`

`BIND 9.9.5-9+deb8u3-Debian (Extended Support Version)`

named.conf.options:

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    key-directory "/etc/bind/keys";

    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
    // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
    // the all-0's placeholder.

    // forwarders {
    //  0.0.0.0;
    // };

    //========================================================================
    // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
    // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
    //========================================================================
    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;
    dnssec-dnskey-kskonly yes;
    sig-validity-interval 21 16;
    inline-signing yes;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };

    // permit lookup of unknown dns names
    recursion no;

    // allow dynamicly new zones
    allow-new-zones yes;
};
```

the cache file `/var/cache/bind/3bf305731dd26307.nzf` has thr rights 0744 and is owned by bind:bind

everything works as expected, i can add zones, stat, load keys and everything - except:

`rndc delzone {ZoneName}`

If i trigger this command (as root in console) i get an `rndc: 'delzone' failed: permission denied`

in the log nothing is showed..

i'm really stuck here - anyone have a clue why this permission error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was, that i was modifying the original cache file `/var/cache/bind/3bf305731dd26307.nzf`.

I removed all entries after `rndc addzone` to my own file structure which i included in the named.conf. After a `rndc reload`, when the entry is not any more in the original cache file located, there is no way to delete the zone via `rndc delzone`.
To gain permissions back, the configuration string of the zone file **MUST** be located in the original cache file `/var/cache/bind/3bf305731dd26307.nzf` when a `rndc reload` is triggered. Seems bind has a need for this internal..

So as the content of `/var/cache/bind/3bf305731dd26307.nzf` says itself - do not edit this file manually, only via `rndc`.

Comment: Hi could you kindly elaborate step by step how you fixed this, having the same issue and i've been using rndc throughout